# how to pass index to component angular 2

Tags: angular

It's not a duplicate. I've done my research. if you still feel, that its not a good question, write the answer in comment and ill delete the question. What I want to do I pass the value of index from HTML element to the component.

```
<ul *ngFor="let person of persons; let i= index" [index]="i">
```

//component of the ^^^^^ view above

```
class appComponent{
@Input() index; // this should get the value of index; but it gives undefined
}
```

Comment: That's not how parameter binding works. `[index]` would be passed to the component `<ul>`.

Comment: Please explain what are you trying to implement.

Comment: The @Input only works with nested child components, not as communication between a template and its class. What are you trying to do with the index? Maybe there is another way to implement what you need.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do with the index?

Comment: i want to change the style based on index on hover

Answer (score 3):

You cannot use **`@Input`** on the same component,

You can do this

```
<div *ngFor="let person of persons;let i = index">
    <div (click)="getIndex(i)">
    </div>
<div>`
```

and then in TS

```
getIndex(index){
   console.log(index);//clicked index
}
```

Comment: but i dont want to bind to click event

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comment :

> I want to change the style based on index on hover

I would suggest to do the following. First, move *ngFor on `<li>`, then set (mouseover) and (mouseout) event to track which li is hovered. Also, use ngStyle if needed (I added event/pair rows coloring just in case):

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let person of persons; let i= index; let even = even" 
      (mouseover)="hovered = i" (mouseout) = "hovered = -1" 
      [ngStyle] = "{'background-color': hovered === i ? 'red' : even ? 'yellow' : 'blue'}">
    {{person.name}}
  </li>
</ul>
```

**[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ztqezp?file=app%2Fapp.component.html)**

Answer (score 0):

When you do *[index]=* in the *ul* the template tries to add the value from this index to a property called 'index' from the ul tagm but this property does not exists on the .
You can bind this value to another property, such as a data-* attribute:

```
<ul [attr.data-index]="index">
```

When you say ' I want to do I pass the value of index from HTML element to the component' this does not make sense: you can't pass data to an html element (they are not angular components). But yu can 'store' a value in a property, as I examplified.

Answer (score 0):

According to what I understood, your requirement is to get the last value of `i` to a component variable. Basically that is the length of the `persons` array. You can simply use the approach `this.input=this.persons.length;`.

`@Input()` has to be used only if you are passing a value from a parent component to a child component.
eg:

```
//parent component class:

@Component({
 selector:'parent-component',
 template: `<child-component [inputVariable]='parentVariable'>`
})

export class ParentComponent{
 parentVariable='foo';
}
```

and

```
//the child component class:

@Component({
selector:'child-component',
template:`<div>{{inputVariable}}<div>`
})
export class ChildComponent{

  @Input()
  inputVariable:any;

}
```